# ¿Cómo actualizo nodejs en WINDOWS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, windows

Tengo que actualizar **npm** y **NodeJS** y no se como!!! Copié este codigo [de aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows) pero no funciona, no actualiza.

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Los pasos que sigo para actualizar NodeJS y npm son los siguientes:

1) Ingresar al sitio de NodeJS y descargar la ultima versión

[Descarga NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2) Instalar NodeJs.msi

3) Abrir Node.js command prompt y ver la versión instalada:

```
node -v
```

4) Actualizar npm utilizando el siguiente comando:

```
npm install npm -g
```

5) Verificar la version de npm

```
npm -v
```

6) Ok

Saludos

Answer (score 3):

En Windows necesitas instalar [NVM](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). Una vez instalado podrás actualizar **NodeJS** con el siguiente comando:

```
nvm install latest
```

[Fuente](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/07/01/update-node-js-on-a-mac-windows-from-terminal/#crayon-57dfb89b98f6e636675994)

Comment: Posiblemente debas hacerlo utilizando una consola abierta con el Administrador

Answer (score 3):

Lo he intentado de varias formas, y las únicas que me funcionan son:

- Instalar [NVM](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases), y después ejecutar el comando *nvm install latest*.
- Eliminar Nodejs de tu computadora, e instalar nuevamente desde la página web de [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/es/).

Espero que si puedas organizar tu problema de versión.