# Angular: ENOENT sparce.js

Tags: javascript, angular

Me sale el siguiente error al crear un nuevo proyecto con Angular desde la consola de Windows.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\ProyectoAngular\node_modules\esprima\bin\esparse.js
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\ProyectoAngular\node_modules\esprima\bin\esparse.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jomi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-13T13_32_23_637Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Estoy aprendiendo Angular y no se si este error me va a generar problemas para poder desarrollar mis aplicaciones.

He buscado y no encuentro concretamente este error.

Gracias!

Comment: `node_modules` guarda todas las librerias para que funcione tu proyecto. Puede que alguno se haya eliminado. Trata instalar el paquete con `npm i esparse`. Si no funciona yo intentaría eliminando esa carpeta e instalando de nuevo el proyecto con `npm install` para que se descargue todo.

Comment: intenté con npm i esparse, y me sale el siguiente mensaje de error: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json', más un Require stack y un montón de ubicaciones. Traté de hacer el npm install y sigue saliendo el error del esparse.js

Comment: En que so lo estas haciendo y con que terminal?

Comment: Windows 10, desde el cmd

Comment: Propongo hagas una instalación limpia de node. Posiblemente haya un error en la instalacion. Por favor busca la `12.16.0 lts`. Puedes intentar seguir estos paso...https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24303/33391